# FloatBuffer OverflowException java

Tags: java, nio, lwjgl, floatbuffer

I have this code here:

```
static ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(16).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
static FloatBuffer matAmbientB = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
static FloatBuffer matAmbientC = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
static FloatBuffer matAmbientD = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
static FloatBuffer matAmbientE = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
static FloatBuffer matAmbientF = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
static FloatBuffer matAmbientG = bytes.asFloatBuffer();
static FloatBuffer matAmbientH = bytes.asFloatBuffer();

    private void initGL()
    { 
        matAmbientB.put(redDiffuseMaterial);
        matAmbientB.rewind();
        matAmbientC.put(whiteSpecularMaterial);
        matAmbientC.rewind();
        matAmbientD.put(greenEmissiveMaterial);
        matAmbientD.rewind();
        matAmbientE.put(whiteSpecularLight);
        matAmbientE.rewind();
        matAmbientF.put(blankMaterial);
        matAmbientF.rewind();
        matAmbientG.put(whiteDiffuseLight);
        matAmbientG.rewind();
        matAmbientH.put(blackAmbientLight);
        matAmbientH.rewind();
    }

    void light ()
    {
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_SPECULAR, matAmbientE.get());
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, matAmbientH.get());
        glLightf(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, matAmbientG.get());
    }
```

When I try to run it, I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferOverflowException
    at java.nio.DirectFloatBufferU.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.nio.FloatBuffer.put(Unknown Source)
    at src.Main.initGL(Main.java:76)
    at src.Main.run(Main.java:45)
    at src.Main.main(Main.java:232)
```

I have looked all over the internet I can't find how to fix the problem (I also don't know what it is). My goal is to convert a float[] to a float, but this is the only way I know how. In c++ there is glLightfv, but in lwjgl there is only glLightf. How do I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to use public final ByteBuffer put(byte[] src) instead of just put(ByteBuffer src) read this http://www.cs.duke.edu/csed/java/jdk1.5/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#put(java.nio.ByteBuffer)

Comment: Quite aside from your error, do you really want to be overwriting the same 16 bytes?

Comment: I found the answer to this question. I put the byte buffer in the method like this: (FloatBuffer)temp.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer of this question somewhere else. In the method I put `(FloatBuffer)bytes.asFloatBuffer().put(lightAmbient).flip()`. This is shorter and works.